# How to detect and install PostgreSQL Server as a prerequisite with Inno Setup?

Tags: postgresql, inno-setup

Anyone have script or procedures to detect (if non existing) and install PostgreSQL Server and then setup the database for any application? Can be both before or after the main installation. It would be really helpful if could help me with it.

Comment: That depends a lot on the operating system and which installation method you want to use.

Comment: I would like to use it on Windows 10. I would prefer to install it before the main installation starts.